# How can I use a loop to re-run this code if there is incorrect input?

Tags: c++

New at C++ and I am trying to implement a loop that executes if a user inputs a character wrong. The idea would be to keep restarting the code until the input is correct. For example, if the user responds to the statement "Please select from the following: A. Unit Vector, B. Cross Product, C. xxxxx" with the the letter D, I would like to output an error message and then restart my code.

PS. I realize the code and organization is not the best right now.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;


int main() 
{   
    string calc_selection;
    int i, j, k;
    int x, y, z, inside_num, a, b, c;
    char comma, pointer;
    double magnitude;

    cout << "Please select from the following: A. Unit Vector, B. Cross Product, C. xxxxx , Intput your letter of choice"; //Basic selectio of calcualtion
    cin >> calc_selection;
    
    if (calc_selection == "A") {
        cout << "Enter your vector values in the following format <X,Y,Z>";
        cin >> pointer >> x >> comma >> y >> comma >> z >> pointer;
        inside_num = (x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z);
        magnitude = sqrt(inside_num);
        cout << "The unit vector is " << (x / magnitude) << "i + " << (y / magnitude) << "j + " << (z / magnitude) << "k";
    }

        if (calc_selection == "B") {
            cout << "Enter your vectors in the following form  <X,Y,Z> , remember for a cross product you need two vectors.";
            cout << "Enter your first vector";
            cin >> pointer >> x >> comma >> y >> comma >> z >> pointer;
            cout << "Enter your second vector";
            cin >> pointer >> a >> comma >> b >> comma >> c >> pointer;
            cout << "Your determinant is as follows:" << '\n' << "i j k" <<"\n" << x << " " << y << " " << z << "\n";
            cout << a <<" "<<b<<" "<< c;
            i = (y * c) - (z * b);
            j = (x * c) - (z * a);
            k = (x * b) - (y * a);
            cout <<"\n" <<"Your vector cross product = " << i << "i + " << j << "j + " << k << "k";

        else {

            cout << "You have input a character or selection incorrectly, try again.";
        }





        }
```

Comment: Use some type of loop.

Comment: This wont compile. Are you asking us about why it doesn't compile? If not, please post code that compiles.

Comment: Move some of your code to functions and learn about `while` loops

Answer (score -1):

You can put the if statmenst into a function, if the user enters something wrong, you can call the same a function that the code is in, a recursion will happen that is when a function calls itself.

https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_functions_recursion.asp

You also forgot the cmath header, you need it for the sqrt function

https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_math.asp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
    
    string calc_selection;
    int i, j, k;
    int x, y, z, inside_num, a, b, c;
    char comma, pointer;
    double magnitude;
        
  void functionQuestion(){
    cout << "Please select from the following: A. Unit Vector, B. Cross Product, C. xxxxx , Intput your letter of choice"; //Basic selectio of calcualtion
    cin >> calc_selection;
    
    if (calc_selection == "A") {
         cout << "Enter your vector values in the following format <X,Y,Z>";
            cin >> pointer >> x >> comma >> y >> comma >> z >> pointer;
            inside_num = (x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z);
            magnitude = sqrt(inside_num);
            cout << "The unit vector is " << (x / magnitude) << "i + " << (y / magnitude) << "j + " << (z / magnitude) << "k";
        }
        if (calc_selection == "B") {
            cout << "Enter your vectors in the following form  <X,Y,Z> , remember for a cross product you need two vectors.";
            cout << "Enter your first vector";
            cin >> pointer >> x >> comma >> y >> comma >> z >> pointer;
            cout << "Enter your second vector";
            cin >> pointer >> a >> comma >> b >> comma >> c >> pointer;
            cout << "Your determinant is as follows:" << '\n' << "i j k" <<"\n" << x << " " << y << " " << z << "\n";
            cout << a <<" "<<b<<" "<< c;
            i = (y * c) - (z * b);
            j = (x * c) - (z * a);
            k = (x * b) - (y * a);
            cout <<"\n" <<"Your vector cross product = " << i << "i + " << j << "j + " << k << "k";
            }
        else {

            cout << "You have input a character or selection incorrectly, try again.";
            functionQuestion();
        }
        
    }
    
int main()
{
    functionQuestion();
}
```

Comment: There’s no need for the stack overhead that recursion imposes here. A simple `while` loop is much more appropriate.